# Stripe - Confirm Card Payment for Multiple Payment Intents

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Docs show how to [create multiple subscriptions for one customer](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiple-products#multiple-subscriptions-for-a-customer) but it never explains how to handle the payment confirmation for the payment intents created for those subscriptions. I need to confirm the payment in one card transaction. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't confirm all the Subscription's PaymentIntents with a single card transaction.

What you can do is to collect the PaymentMethod from the first Subscription PaymentIntent submission, set that PaymentMethod as a [default](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method) one for the customer.

Every Subscription created for that customer will be charged from that PaymentMethod. You can learn more about [setting PaymentMethod for Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment-methods-setting).

If you want to absolutely have a single transaction/payment for all Subscriptions, you need to implement a workaround. You can create a separate Invoice that represents all the Subscriptions' total amount. And create zero amount Subscriptions for the customer (using 0 amount prices, 100% off coupons). Note that this is not recommended and is a workaround that requires a lot of manual/custom integration.

Or simply create a [Subscription schedule that starts in a future](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#start-subscription-future) date (target the next renewal date)

Comment: For Europe afaik all transactions must be confirmed using 3DSecure. So if I use the approach of setting the PaymentMethod as default will it still require transaction confirmations for the following PaymentIntents?

Comment: That depends on the issuer's bank to request 3DSecure or not. In order to handle these cases you can setup webhook for Subscription:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#additional-action

Comment: This is a partially correct answer. There is no need to create zero amount Subscriptions. All I had to do is to set the start date of the subscription to what would be the renewal date and charge the necessary amount as part of the invoice as you referred to. @os4m37 , if you correct your answer I will be happy to mark it as the accepted answer.  I just don't want to misguide anyone by accepting it as is.

Comment: You can't create a Subscription that starts in a future date. You are referring maybe to Subscription Schedules instead. But make sense, what you are suggesting. I updated the answer thanks!